# Can anyone explain me what is state and mutable data?

Tags: java, javascript, functional-programming, immutability

> In computer science, functional programming is a programming paradigm
>   that treats computation as the evaluation of mathematical functions
>   and avoids state and mutable data.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming

Can anyone explain me what is state and mutable data? Can anyone give me examples in either JAVA or JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mutable suggest anything that can change, i.e. an int

```
int a = 0;
System.out.prtinln(a); //prints 0
a = 2;
System.out.prtinln(a); //now prints 2, so its mutable
```

In java a string is immutable. you cannot change the string value only its reference.

```
String s1 = "Hello";
System.out.println(s1); //prints Hello
String s2 = s1;
s1 = "Hi";
System.out.println(s2); //prints "Hello" and not "Hi"
```

State is something which an instance of a class will have (an Object).

If an Object has certain values for its attributes its in a diffrent state then another Object of the same class with diffrent attribute values

Comment: Anyone can explain it better? o.O

Answer (score 6):

State refers collectively to the data stored in the object that determines the current properties of the object. For example, if you have a `BankAccount` object, the owner of the account and the amount of money in it represent the *state* of the account.

However, not all state is bad for functional programming, only the *mutable*<sup>+</sup> one is not acceptable. For example, the characters of which a string is composed is that string's state. If you cannot change the content of the string, it is said to have an *immutable* state. This fits well with functional programming paradigm.

---

<sup>+</sup> *mutable* is a fancy word for "changeable".

Comment: What you call "nonmutable state" I would call "value".

Answer (score 3):

Mutable state is everything that can make a function return a different value, despite it being called with the same arguments.

Simple example in Java:

```
public static double badSqrt(double x) {
    double r = Math.sqrt(x);
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 42L == 0L) return r;
    return r + 0.000000001;
}
```

This function computes a slightly incorrect result sometimes. We say that `badSqrt` is impure, because its result does not solely depend on its argument (and constants).

For the person debugging a program that contains calls to badSqrt() or impure functions in general this is a nightmare. Often, the program seems to work, but once in a while, wrong results are delivered. Unless the function is clearly documented or the source code is available, it'll be hard to track the bug.

In such cases, it is said that the behaviour of the functions depends on mutable state. This is state that could be changed (mutated) by completely unrelated parts of the program, or, like in the example, by *another* program (the operating system).

Answer (score 2):

A classic example of an immutable object is an instance of the Java String class.

```
 String s = “ABC”;

 s.toLowerCase();

 System.out.println(s);
```

**Output = ABC**

This is because s continues referencing its immutable String. If you want to mutate s, a different approach is needed:

```
s = s.toLowerCase();
```

This will create a ***new*** reference. Now the String s references a new String object that contains "*abc*".

Answer (score 1):

suppose 
int i=5;

now the state of variable i is that , now it has contained value 5.

suppose now i have set i=7;

now the state of variable i is that , now it has contained value 7, it has replaces 5.

> if change in value is possible then it is called as-mutable that means
>   we can change state here.

if change in value is not  possible then it is called as-immutable.

Comment: And building on this, an object's state is based on the state of all of its fields. If one of an object's fields changes state, then the object state changes. If an object's fields **can** change state, the object is considered mutable. If an object's fields can't change state (once the object has been created), it's considered immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest explanation of the difference between state and mutable state.  Almost every language has built in methods and functions that we can call to do different things.  These methods and functions maintain its own state and we can manipulate it depending on the parameter(s) we use.  Different parameters gives different parameters(arguments) can return different values.  Now, lets say we make a constructor(JavaScript) to store our own state.  We then write a function to manipulate state based on user input, and after we write it we don't change the parameter(s), even when it's called.  BUT the content inside state can be changed using setState, resulting in endless changes from the same function without changing the parameter(s).

Answer (score -1):

State data is static. I.e. hypercard. Mutable data resembles more of a binary assembled artificial movement paradigm. QED -Bryan Meluch Purdue 1997 [verb.atim] Web

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)